# Are these bushes sun damaged?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, shrubs

I have two of these bushes -I'm not sure what they are, maybe somebody knows? It looks like they might be sun damaged. I know that there used to be a tree nearby that provided some shade, which makes me think they are getting too much sun. They have small white flowers in the spring. Also, I see them around a lot so I think they are pretty common landscape bushes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this is [*Euonomys alatus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euonymus_alatus). The red color showing on the leaves is chlorosis. The red color is always underlying, but comes out when the chlorophyll loses concentration. That is what causes the red fall color.

The red on your plant might be caused by several factors, but too much sun isn't one of them. It looks like the shrub is suffering from nutrient (probably nitrogen) deprivation. Try fertilizing with a balanced fertilizer every couple weeks.

Another thing you could check is the soil pH. This often affects leaf color.

Comment: What kind of fertilizer would you recommend? Fish fertilizer.. fertilizer stake.. miracle gro?

Comment: @Ultravi01 I'd recommend using a soluble fertilizer (miracle gro is fine) for now, to green it up fast, but after the leaves look healthy, you an use a slower release fertilizer, like spikes, or something organic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are the shrub called Burning Bush or [Euonymus alatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euonymus_alatus). It might be the misnamed cultivar 'Compactus' which can still get quite large with time. The identifying keys are the paired leaves with a light sawtooth shape on the perimeter of each leaf.  A more definitive identification would be the corky wings that are seen on older growth.

This shrub is native to to central and northern China, Japan, and Korea and was introduced to North America in the 1860's. If left alone it often grows into a plant up to eight feet (2.5 Meters) wide and tall.  It is very popular due to it's good red colour in the fall if correctly located and bright pink or orange fruit.

It is a tough and hardy shrub, so much so, that it is considered [invasive](http://www.invasiveplantatlas.org/subject.html?sub=3023) in eastern North America and sale is prohibited in a few states. Consider the [black chokecherry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronia), particularly some of the cultivars such as Aronia arbutifolia 'Brilliantissima' instead.

The red colour on the new growth could indicate a premature colour change due to stress or even cool temperatures given the odd summer we have had so far in Eastern North America.

Comment: +1 yup, it's a Euonymus. And it is invasive.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. What could be causing stress? I'm guessing it has something to do with either too much water or too little?